# HTML5 Canvas bounce ball from line free in the room

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

i want to let a ball bounce from a line that i can move around on the canvas. Everything works fine, i detect the collision with my line correctly but i don't know how to solve the correct bouncing angle.
Bouncing from the borders works perfectly (20 is the radius of my ball / adding 0.01 to the velocity makes the ball faster with the time). This is how i solved the bouncing from the walls.

```
if (this.posY - 20 <= 0) {
      //bounce top
      this.velY = -this.velY;
      this.posY = this.radius;
      this.playSound();
    } else if (this.posX - this.radius <= 0) {
      //bounce left
      this.velX = -this.velX + 0.01;
      this.posX = this.radius;
      this.playSound();
    } else if (this.posX + this.radius >= this.canvasWidth) {
      //bounce right
      this.velX = -this.velX - 0.01;
      this.posX = this.canvasWidth - this.radius;
      this.playSound();
    }
```

For the line i have the coordinates of the start- and endpoint and i have the coordinates of the ball.
I move the ball by updating his position coordinates and draw them again.

[image: image to understand more what i want]

Comment: This answer has what you want.https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303640/3877726

Comment: yes but the answer in this question is a little bit overpowered and there is a lots of code i don't understand. I'm very new to JS. He is creating multiple lines and balls and moves the lines random? around?

Comment: The answer has a step by step solution involving one static line with one ball. You can not solve the problem with less.